# JavaScript: extract a URL from a string once a space is encountered

Tags: javascript, regex

I am not good at regex but I want to extract a URL from a string followed by a space. For example I have a string:

```
I am working on a website http://www.example.com/ and I want to find this URL.
```

The closest working regex is this

```
/(^https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,10})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/i
```

But It needs to pick URL followed by a space and not just after the two characters of the domain extension. Please help.

Comment: If I am typing http://yahoo.com, it captures till 'http://y', I need to capture like 'http://yahoo.com '. Please notice a space after .com

Comment: Try : https://regex101.com/r/rW8zC7/1

Comment: Sorry Shekhar! It is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have re-worked your regex into something that will match what you want, I believe:

```
/(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:[\da-z-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,10}(?:\/[^\s/]+)*\/?\s/gi
```

[See in Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sZ7dC9/5)

```js
var regex = /(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:[\da-z-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,10}(?:\/[^\s/]+)*\/?\s/gi;

var lines = [
  "You can match a URL http://subdomain.domain.com which includes a subdomain",
  "But not one that...this uses the http protocol (see http://example.com)",
  "I am working on a website http://example.com/ and I want to find this URL.", 
  "This URL www.example.com will also match",
  "The URL example.com will match again",
  "You can have http://example.com several urls www.example.com in the example.com text you are parsing",
  "URLs containing trailing information example.com/foo/bar will be matched",
  "and complex URLS like http://subdomain.domain.com/foo/bar/file.txt/baz?param=value&param2=img.jpg#cointainsHash can also be matched",
  "although invalid looking URLs like http://example.com///foo will not be",
  "It will also fail if it's at the end of the line http://example.com"
]

lines.forEach(string => console.log(string, string.match(regex)))
```

Explanation:

**Regex components**

`(?:https?:\/\/)?` - optionally it will start with **http://** or **https://**. This is surrounded in non-capturing group.

`(?:www\.)?` - optionally, start with *www.*. NOTE: this is actually superfluous, as the next part of the pattern will match it regardless. It can be omitted but might be needed if the domain pattern is changed.

`(?:[\da-z-]+\.)+` catch one or more components of the URL each of which should contain one or more more alphanumeric, dot or dash characters followed by a dot. This will match ensure you pick up subdomains, like `subdomain.example.com` or TLD components like `example.co.uk` or both: `subdomain.example.co.uk` in addition to just the base domain name.

`[a-z]{2,10}` match two to ten letters for a final TLD

`(?:\/[^\s/]+)*` non-matching group containing a forward slash followed by one or more characters that are not spaces or forward slashes. The group is repeated any amount of times to account for `/foo` and `/bar` parts of `example/foo/bar`. The exclusion of `/` makes sure only content between forward slashes is matched, the exclusion of whitespace ensures it doesn't "overrun" and accidentally match a space after the URL. The reasoning behind *blacklisting* characters is that content can be varied, which can include dots, dashes, underscores and even characters in other alphabets, alongside query parameters (utilising `?` and `&`) a URL hash (using `#`) or a combination. Assuming you don't want to accept all characters, this should be restricted. If you want to verify the *validity* of a URL, for example, ensuring that `?param=value` comes *before* `#hash` and is correctly separated by `&` signs then those matches need to be separated out. On the other hand, that would be a rather heavy-handed validation - for most cases simply using `[^\s/]` would be enough to recognise a valid-looking URL.

`\/?` optional forward slash at the end of the URL

`\s` must match any whitespace character. If you want a literal space then change that to the space character  if you want to catch a URL if its at the end of the input string, then change this to `(?:\s|$)` or `(?: |$)` depending on whether you want any whitespace or just the space character.

**Flags**

`i` case-insensitive match

`g` global match - it will return all URLs in the string. If removed, it will return one.

I have removed some of the groupings as they were superfluous.

A word of warning: this regex will *only* work for latin characters. Domain names in Cyrillic or Chinese, for example, will not be matched. There is little that can be done for this with core JavaScript, as it has no Unicode support for the moment. If you want to support those, then I suggest using a third party regular expression library like [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/). An alternative is to re-write this regular expression without mentioning any letters, however, it will most likely be vulnerable to flagging false-positives.

Some more notes: this will not match all valid URLs but it works within the limitations proposed. For example, `example.com:8080` will not match but something like `a.b.c.de` will because it contains components that can be interpreted as subdomains. Moreover, TLDs will not be ensured to be valid - aside from non-latin TLDs, some may contain more than 10 characters. Assuming you don't need to ensure the total validity of a URL but only want to match something that looks like one, this would work.

Comment: According to your regexp, if the string is `"...this uses the http protocol (see http://example.com)"` the result is `["...this "]`. Not exactly working...

Comment: @R.Schifini did you _really_ downvote for this reason alone? Shall I assume that you thought I downvoted your answer, so you decided to be petty? Well, I've made an update.

Comment: Just upvoted your answer for your effort, I will not check if it work or not, it is none of my interest. I was just pointing out that the example you used to break my regexp was neither working with your solution.

Comment: It will not match all valid URLs because I was using OP's regex as a basis of what he wanted. I further added a note to mention this. A regex that matches all valid URLs is going to be 1. an overkill 2. probably impossible in plain JS. The sample here will cover a lot of common URL patterns and will not match some false ones as easily. I've detailed each of the significant segments in the regex to explain why and how they work. This can serve as a basis for it to be modified as needed, since OP's requirements were short, so I don't know if the suggestion is sufficient or not.

Comment: @vlaz, perfect! This is a very good solution and satisfies almost all doubts. I would take this solution. Thank you for your effort. Writing such a long and with such a detailed solution shows how kind you are to my problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: If i take an image, for example, your thumbnail, it doesn't work. https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAGH9.jpg. Probably doesn't pick after last backward slash.

Comment: That was because I assumed you were only after the base URL ending with the TLD. I have added a section on matching longer URLs.

Comment: It is now matching to my needs. It was better earlier, now it is even more better. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

I've prepared a little demo for you here: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/qaqdNA

Would the following work in your case?

```
var str = 'I am working on a website http://www.example.com/ and I want to find this URL.'

// capture whole url, including trailing space
var url = (str.match(/http[^\s]*[\s]/) || [])[0]
console.log(url); // 'http://www.example.com/ '

// capture url without http, include trailing space
var urlNoHttp = (str.match(/(?:http:\/\/)(.*?\s)/) || [])[1];
console.log(urlNoHttp); // 'www.example.com '
```

Comment: See [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PGbqYR) Codepen about why this isn't a solution.  He specifically said he wanted a space before the string.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following regular expression:

```
rxp = / http[^ ]+/
```

This will match a space followed by http and grab everything until a space is found

Then do:

```
stringWithURL.match(rxp)[0].slice(1)
```

This will strip the first space character and return a string instead of an array.

For the case:

```
stringWithURL = "I am working on a website http://www.example.com/ and I want to find this URL."
```

Will give as result:

```
"http://www.example.com/"
```

And if you want to capture this as you are typing it, then do the capture after every keystroke and the result will keep growing until a space is typed, then then URL will be complete.

Comment: I am typing and not just doing copy paste. So it picks right after 'http'.

Comment: `...this uses the http protocol (see http://example.com)` would produce two matches.

Answer (score -1):

You're already using regular expressions, just add a space before it in order to require it to be a new word:

```
/ (ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/i
```

Will match most common URLs inside of text blocks as long as there is a space before it.  This solution also accepts ftp, but simple remove it from the list if you only want http/https like so:

```
/ (http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/i
```

Credit to @Roman for the initial solution.

Comment: This solution is not working. Though I already have considered Tazo Todua answer, your effort is also appreciated. It may work in some other context and is useful.

Comment: @OmPrakash I think you may need to be a little more specific in how it doesn't work, if you look at a site like regex101.com you generate code for a language of your choice which should, in theory, work.  Testing this seems to work for all test cases you've provided and some I've made up :)

Answer (score -1):

another solution:

```js
var str='I am working on a website http://www.example.com/ and I want to find this URL.';
var Matches = (/http(.*?)\s/g).exec(str);
console.log(Matches);
```

p.s. if you want `ftp:/` or other type of schemes, accommodate the script yourself.

Comment: Again, this answer fails at the same point as @Piotr Berebecki's answer.  The question wants to only match if there is a space before the Regex, this matches even if you get a string like hellohttp://www.example.com/